# Calendar application for Android with tasks and richtext support

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar

I am looking for the application compatible with Android 5.x which supports the following functions:

1. Supports remote [ICS](https://icalendar.org/) calendar(s), e.g. Google calendar.
2. Supports tasks, i.e. can display/create/edit events from special [Google task calendar](http://blogoscoped.com/archive/2009-04-15-n26.html). Task in this case is just a normal event, which can additionally be marked as *Completed*. Do not mess with [advanced tasks support](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48700/calendar-with-support-for-todo-tasks-support), like carrying forward until completed – that is nice to have, but not required.
3. Supports rich text in event description. This feature was introduced recently in online Google Calendar and applications that do not support it simply display HTML tags literally e.g. `<b>Agenda:</b><br>...`.
4. Can be put to a home screen as a widget (all apps below support this).

I have installed and played with the following apps:

- [Google Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.calendar) – [does not support tasks](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/kg_aooQmESY) (-), supports richtext in description (+)
- [Wave Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.esites.ecal)  (discontinued) – supports tasks (+), does not support richtext in description (-), fails to create new event (-)
- [aCalendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.withouthat.acalendar) – does not support tasks (-), supports richtexts in description (+)
- [DigiCal Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digibites.calendar) – does not support tasks (-), does not support richtext in description (-)
- [Personal Calendar Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.miwi.personalcalendarfree) – does not support tasks (-), does not support richtext in description (-), [FAQ](http://www.miwiapps.de/faq) is only in German

The winner:

- [Business Calendar 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appgenix.bizcal) – supports tasks (+), supports richtext in description (+)

Further options are appreciated.

Comment: Nice question! Note: If integration with remote ICS calendar is a requirement, please write it clearly, thanks :-)

Comment: Done. P.S. Honestly I can hardly imagine usecase for mobile application that does not support remote calendars. And ICS is de-factor interchange standard for remote calendars.

Comment: aCalendar+ supports tasks.

Comment: @dma_k: Actually the only answer so far was an Android app that does not support ICS, that's why it is better to write down everything, even if that may sound obvious to you it might not be for others :-)

Comment: @vclaw: Thanks for aCalendar+ reference. I would love to test it, but it costs $$. If you have more interesting information to share about extra functions you like in aCalendar+ then make a complete answer.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul: I would be interested to here the name of the app you have in mind. Please, share.